# How to configure with terraform two ECS clusters in the same VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-ecs

[image]

I am trying to add a new cluster in my vpc by using terraform , this cluster will handle heavy calculation and un other activites. But i have no idea how to configure redirection for request from internet Cluster1 must be sensitive to a cluser1.mydomain.com and cluster to cluster2.mydomain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General steps are following:

- **Register** `mydomain.com` in Route53 (R53) for example.
- Create **two A alias records** (`cluser1.mydomain.com` and `cluser2.mydomain.com`) in R53 pointing to ALB DNS.
- Setup **two target groups** (TGs) for the ALB. First TG (TG1) for ECS service one, while the TG2 for service two.
- On the ALB setup **single listener** (e.g. HTTP 80), with **two different rules**. For example:

  - Rule one will be based on `Host header` equal to `cluser1.mydomain.com` which forwards to TG1.
  - Rule one will be based on `Host header` equal to `cluser2.mydomain.com` which forwards to TG2.
  - A compulsory default rule  (or use 2 as default rule).

Comment: thank i will try this solution. in both cluster i have  autoscaling groupe  by doing as you mention is there any case where i will misslead my infrastructure i dont want cluster1 to scall when cluster2 is flooded

Comment: @AllGlenn Scaling is not managed by ALB. Its a separate process at ECS service level. So I don't see a way how you could scale second service, while first one is flooded.

Comment: side effect i got an error  "This server could not prove that it is cron-cluser1.mydomain.com; its security certificate is from cluser2.mydomain.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
Is there any way to link both Url to the same server ?

Comment: thank you it works like a charm after strungling with ssl certificates and how listeners work i would recommande this link to anyone facing the same issue :

[link](https://medium.com/cognitoiq/terraform-and-aws-application-load-balancers-62a6f8592bcf)